# can we do the same thing for grid checkcolumns?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I want to do something similar to this fiddle :https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20rt
but the difference is that he has done it for **checkbox** xtype but I want it for **checkcolumn** .Please let me know if we can do like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use headerCheckbox config.
Configure as true to display a checkbox below the header text.

Clicking the checkbox will check/uncheck all records.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {  
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'checkcolumn', 
        headerCheckbox:true, 
    }]
});
```